# Can we add custom user attributes to Cloud Directory identity source of Bluemix SSO Service?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am using Bluemix SSO service for user authentication and configured the Cloud Directory identity source as my identity provider. The SSO implementation is working perfectly fine for the Bluemix applications.

However, I have a need to add few custom user attributes and retrieve them as part of the user profile details once the authentication is successful. The Cloud Directory identity source only supports name & email as the user attributes and doesn't provide any feature to add additional custom attributes.

Is it possible to add any custom user attributes to Cloud Directory identity source? If not, what is the best way to configure the custom user attributes when using Bluemix SSO service?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add additional custom attributes using the Cloud Directory of Bluemix SSO (example: roles). There is not a best way to configure the custom user attributes, but you could develop your own login system. For example if you are using Bluemix nodejs runtime you could use the passport module and store all user information in a specific table of your DB. In this way you can manage the login and other custom fields. An alternative is to use SSO Cloud Directory, retrieve the username information from the SSO service in the session and use it as a key to retrieve other DB fields (roles, numbers, address).